# eclipse: remote debugging a tomcat server behind a firewall

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, remote-debugging, ssh-tunnel

After starting tomcat with jpda on, while at my company I can remote debug a bunch of web applications in eclipse. For a number of reasons I am now in need of developing and remote debugging those same webapps from outside the company firewall, and i can only access that server via ssh on port 22.

I tunneled most needed ports (svn, nexus, tomcat itself, from the server or via the server) to localhost and those services work fine, but I cannot start the eclipse debugger in any way; i'm getting "connection timed out while waiting for packet XXX" or "connection refused" from the second time i try on.
Checking with nmap on the server, it reports the port open before the first connection attempt, and it becomes closed after that. I get no interesting output log in catalina.out

The command i use to start the tunnel is:

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 user@mycompany.com
```

iptables was temporarily stopped both on the server and in the local machine for testing.

Am i missing something? Do I need to forward some other port to localhost? Or is it in some way involved name resolution?

**EDIT**

Open ports before connection attemp from eclipse:

```
root@lnxulisse:/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/bin# lsof -p 2147  -n |grep TCP
java    2147 root    4u  IPv4 640850      0t0     TCP *:8000 (LISTEN)
java    2147 root   38u  IPv6 640859      0t0     TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
java    2147 root   40u  IPv6 640865      0t0     TCP *:https (LISTEN)
java    2147 root   46u  IPv6 640908      0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:18005 (LISTEN)
java    2147 root   48r  IPv6 642625      0t0     TCP 172.24.0.82:48347->172.24.0.82:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
java    2147 root  181u  IPv6 640891      0t0     TCP 172.24.0.82:60353->172.24.0.82:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
```

and after:

```
java    2147 root    4u  IPv6 642769      0t0     TCP 172.24.0.82:48956->172.24.0.82:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
java    2147 root    5u  IPv4 640851      0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:8000->127.0.0.1:34193 (ESTABLISHED)
java    2147 root   38u  IPv6 640859      0t0     TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
java    2147 root   40u  IPv6 640865      0t0     TCP *:https (LISTEN)
java    2147 root   46u  IPv6 640908      0t0     TCP 127.0.0.1:18005 (LISTEN)
java    2147 root  181u  IPv6 640891      0t0     TCP 172.24.0.82:60353->172.24.0.82:mysql (ESTABLISHED)
```

exact eclipse error returned is:

```
Exception occurred during launch
Failed to connect to remote JVM. Connection timed out.
Timeout occurred while waiting for packet 204.
```

(the packet number varies on each attempt).

in `workspace/.metadata/.log` i get:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-07-17 18:43:53.024
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.core.net.proxy.IProxyService", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5000ms) for thread "Thread[Thread-6,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.1.r35x_20090812-1200 [232]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.core.net.proxy.IProxyService" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.1.r35x_20090812-1200.jar" by thread "Thread-6".
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1073)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:278)
[...]

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.ide 4 4 2011-07-17 18:43:53.028
!MESSAGE Proxy service could not be found.
```

eclipse is configured for direct internet connection.

**EDIT 2**

I think the solution might be here:

http://blog.cantremember.com/debugging-with-jconsole-jmx-ssh-tunnels/

but i have some trouble understanding his JNDI/RMI settings, and to what extent that applies to my configuration.

**EDIT 3**

This is a clarification for those answering "use `<lan|local ip address>` instead of `<localhost>`"

- computer A: my workstation in the company
- computer B: my workstation at home
- computer C: server running tomcat

B and C are in two different sub-networks in the same network infrastructure; only connections to port 22 of C from outside are allowed (and somewhat "proxied", I don't know network internals).

A is "outside" (my dsl connection with dynamic ip address).

```
Debugging on C from B via ssh tunnel -> works
Debugging on C from A via ssh tunnel -> connection timed out while waiting for packet XXX
```

Comment: @ram did you see my question "EDIT 2"? the answer should be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I am answering myself after a long time; in my specific case, the solution was to put eclipse JVM in listening mode:

```
Connection Type: "Standard (Socket Listen)"
```

and reverse the direction of the tunnel:

```
ssh -L 8001:localhost:8001 user@work   (run on server (S), "localhost" is W)
ssh -R 8001:localhost:8001 user@work   (run at home (H), "localhost" is W)
```

Some explanation: as in the question, my situation was:

```
  H  -------------------> S     not working  ( ssh -L 8001:S:8001 user@S  from H)
  H           W  -------> S     working      ( ssh -L 8001:S:8001 user@S  from W)
 home        work      server
```

While reversing like this:

```
  H  <------- W           S     ssh -R 8001:localhost:8001 user@W  (from H)
  H           W  <------- S     ssh -L 8001:localhost:8001 user@W  (from S)
 home        work      server
```

did the trick. In other words, whatever is written on S:8001, is forwarded to W:8001, and whatever in turn is written to W:8001, is forwarded to H:8001, where my eclipse JVM is listening.

The tomcat JVM on S should be started with server=n, with arguments:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=n,address=8001
```

Answer (score 10):

[This article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) suggests that the default port on which the remote Java virtual machine (JVM) is listening in debugging mode is 1044. You should tunnel the port on which the remote JVM is running as well.

---

More generally, you could run wireshark/tcpdump to see to which port connection attempts are made when starting the debugger.

---

**EDIT**:

A few more things I would try:

- check on the remote host (e.g. with `ps auxwww` if it's Linux) with which arguments (look for what comes behind `-Xrunjdwp` or with `lsof -p PID_OF_JVM_TO_BE_DEBUGGED` on which TCP port it listens (look for lines with `TCP` and `LISTEN` in the `lsof` output)
- make sure that the JVM on the remote host listens on the `lo` interface, not the network interface (that's what you specify with the `localhost` in the `-L` option to ssh).
- Does starting the debugger by hand on the machine where you start eclipse with `jdb -attach localhost:8000` work ? (you could also try this on the remote host to ensure the debugger is running on the port 8000)
- make sure that eclipse tries to connect to `localhost` (when not specifying a bind address before the first 8000 with the `-L` option ssh listens on the `lo` interface)

Comment: I'm explicitly setting the port to 8000 in tomcat startup script (and remote debugging works while inside the company network indeed); will try with tcpdump to see if there is some other connection attempt, but in that case the error i get ("timeout waiting for packet") would be misleading.

Comment: `connection timed out` could be due to the firewall simply ignoring (discarding) the packets of the connection attempt (instead of sending a packet which says that there is nothing running on this port and immediately refuse the connection attempt).

Comment: thanks for your help; actually the connection runs for some seconds before timeout, and the error reported which packet number was "late" (or never arrived). Please look at my edits in the question for some more details

Comment: do you understand what the service on port 18005 is ? (I'm just wondering whether this is what you need to tunnel in addition)

Comment: yep, it's the tomcat port for shutdown, in the <Server> tag (default is 8005, but that is taken by another tomcat instance)

Answer (score 10):

I often had this problem when doing remote debugging. I do not know the exact reason for this problem, but I used the below solution and maybe it works for you, too:

instead of

```
ssh -L 8000:localhost:8000 user@remotehost
```

is used

```
ssh -L 8000:remotehost:8000 user@remotehost
```

for creating the SSH tunnel (note the remotehost instead of localhost between the port numbers in the second example). Instead of the remote host's name, you can also use the normal IP address of the remote host (not the loopback address 127.0.0.1, but the true local network IP address).

Hope it helps and good luck!

Comment: good point but this does not solve my issue; look comment in daniel answer

Comment: And for those on Google Cloud: Use `gcloud compute ssh --ssh-flag="-L 8787:INTERNAL_IP:8787"  INSTANCE`.
`%INSTANCE%` as per https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh  didn't worked for me but the internal does.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming the remote Tomcat instance has been started with something like `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n`, try this command:

```
ssh -L 8000:0.0.0.0:8000 user@mycompany.com -N
```

On my Mac, I tried out `ssh -L 10701:localhost:10700 user@localhost -N` locally, where a Tomcat instance was started with `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=10700,suspend=n`, and attempting to attach on port 10701 within Eclipse, I kept seeing "Failed to connect to remote VM com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.ClosedConnectionException". By changing the tunnel command to `ssh -L 10701:0.0.0.0:10700 user@localhost -N`, Eclipse was able to attach.

Comment: On my linux system I had no problems attaching to the server using localhost, while inside the company network; the problem arises when trying to attach to an "inside" ip address from outside, with the  firewall letting only connections to port 22. Also note that the exception you get is different, you get a connection closed by peer, while I was getting a timeout exception.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please give the exact parameters of the -Xrunjdwp parameter?

Also do you have tried different methods for debugging (server=y/n, suspend=y/n)?

Perhaps inversing the connection (let the tomcat connect to the debugger instead of letting the debugger connect to tomcat) may help.